# Ghostly book I can't remember the name of

Tags: story-identification, books, ghost

I once read a book about a family that moved into an old Manor house. The family experience ghostly writings on a wall, and if I recall correctly they carry out a written conversation with the author of the wall writings.

The 'ghost' was a character from perhaps the 17th or 18th Century and in his day it was his house, while the family was very modern.

To cut a very long story short (because I have a hazy memory of this book) the twist of the book explains that not only do the family think the author of the writings is a ghost, but the ghost also thinks that they are ghosts/alien/paranormal beings. So both seem to believe that the others are paranormal.

I can't remember what it was called and so I ask the community.

'The Others' seems to ring a bell with me, but I don't know if that is because I have seen the film of the same name that has striking similarity with this book, either way I can't match the book with this name. I would very much like to find this book again!

Comment: At first I thought you meant that the book was ghostly in some way, ot about ghostly happenings.  What would a "ghostly" book be like?

Comment: Hard to read, I would imagine.

Answer (score -2):

Is this *The Ghost of Thomas Kempe* by Penelope Lively?

Comment: What makes you think this is the book OP is looking for?

Comment: Sadly this isn't the book. When I saw the answer I thought perhaps this was right, but when I looked into it I realised I recognised it only because I read it as a child. Thanks for chipping in though.